# Displaying a signed int as unsigned in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a simple way of displaying a signed integer as unsigned when binding to a variable in WPF.

I have a value that is handled as a signed integer in the code but I need to display it in its unsigned form (don't ask why, customers and their lack of understanding of datatypes...).

I'm not interested in changing the value from a TextBox or similar, but rather just display it in a TextBlock

EDIT:
To clarify I mean the actual value as achieved by a type cast.

Ex. (using Int16 for readability)

-10 should display as 65,526, not as 10.

Comment: How do you display an 'unsigned' value? Do you mean that, say -10 becomes 10?

Comment: Good point, I should have explained that. Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: It seems like a converter for this should be trivial.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably going down that road. I was kind of hoping it would be possible to typecast in the xaml somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a value converter which returns appropriate value.

Comment: yes, simple... if less then zero, 65536 PLUS the negative value.

Comment: Yeah I'll go for a converter. But rather than using addition I just cast the value to its unsigned form and return it